# Hibernate with JNDI: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'

Tags: hibernate, spring, tomcat, jndi

I tried to use Hibernate for working with MySQL through JNDI but can't (from catalina.out):

```
INFO: Deploying web application archive mystamps.war
Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.getProtocol(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:507)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.knownURL(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:476)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.acceptsURL(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:307)
```

(I reduce full stack trace because it's useless: no cause or any other exceptions.)

spring-servlet.xml:

```
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/mystamps" />

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="ru.mystamps.web.dao" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

/etc/tomcat6/server.xml:

```
<Host name="my-stamps" appBase="webapps"
    unpackWARs="false" xmlValidation="false"
    xmlNamespaceAware="false">
</Host>
```

/etc/tomcat6/Catalina/my-stamps/mystamps.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context path="" docBase="mystamps" allowLinking="true" reloadable="true">
    <Resource name="jdbc/mystamps" auth="Containter"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
        username="root" password="password" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mystamps" />
</Context>
```

I use following versions: Spring MVC 3.0.5, Hibernate 3.6.2.Final, MySQL 5.1.52 , mysql-connector-java 5.1.15 (located at /usr/share/tomcat6/lib) and Tomcat 6.0.30

I use google and try to fix it by myself, but without luck :(

Can you help me -- what's I doing wrong?

TIA

Comment: Does the dataSource works as expected using straight JDBC?

Comment: @Piyush yes, it is worked well with plain JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the mysql-connector jar file in the WEB-INF/lib folder of your packaged war file?

Or maybe the following link can be helpful: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=430133

Comment: Thanks for reply! I tried a both but it does not solve my problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Had this same error, when I moved the location that the JNDI is declared to context.xml and my error went away. This error means that spring cannot find the JNDI infformation. There was no need for a link in the server.xml

```
/etc/tomcat6/context.xml

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context path="" docBase="mystamps" allowLinking="true" reloadable="true">
    <Resource name="jdbc/mystamps" auth="Containter"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
        username="root" password="password" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mystamps" />
</Context>
```

Ref: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html

Hope this helps!